# Обрезание картинки в html

Tags: html, css

Есть картинка и блок, который зависит от высоты экрана. Картинка является фоном этого блока. Если размер картинки больше размера блока, то она автоматически обрезается одинаково со всех краев. Как сделать так, чтобы обрезалось, к примеру, только снизу, а верх оставался нетронутым?

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему через `background-position`